# Use wifi for internet but access a printer over ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, network-printer, system-preferences

In my office I have a Wifi connection and a LAN connection the printers are connected via LAN. LAN and Wifi both have internet but the LAN internet is slower.

I want to use internet through Wifi but printer through LAN at the same time.

I have set the preferences in advanced adapter settings but it's not working.

How can I do this?

Comment: Windows does not handle using both LAN and Wireless Networks well.  The simplest solution would be to connect the LAN printers to the wireless access point in question instead.

Comment: Given that what you're posting doesn't make sense (LAN should outperform WIFI easily) can I safely assume that LAN and WIFI are not connected through the same internet connection?

Comment: Can you separate your network into 2 subnets and set your ethernet adapters and the printers to use the second subnet? That way, you can't contact the printer from a wireless adapter, because they aren't on the same network.

Comment: It's tad difficult to advise without the knowledge of your network design, but in general you'd need to tweak routing table, maybe this will help: http://superuser.com/questions/455965/how-to-give-preference-over-one-network-connection-over-another/456038#456038