# How do I ensure the Internet works on Windows 7 with 2 simultaneous wireless connections?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

My church has two separate wireless networks, one called **ChurchInternet** which broadcasts on a 2.4 GHz frequency and another called **ChurchAudio** which broadcasts on a 5 GHz frequency. Both are broadcast by (separate) Linksys routers. **ChurchInternet** is connected to the Internet while **ChurchAudio** has no Internet connectivity and is used for connecting to the sound equipment (we have a nice new mixer). We don't want anyone connecting to the **ChurchAudio** (which is why it's separate), but we do allow people with the password to connect to **ChurchInternet**.

We've got a desktop computer running Windows 7 in the church that we would like to be able to connect to both. This computer has two separate USB wireless adapters.

One of the adapters is a little older than the other, and can only see 2.4 GHz networks. So I obviously want that one to connect to **ChurchInternet**. That first adapter is called `Wireless Connection 13`

The second (newer) adapter is capable of seeing both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz networks. So that has to be the one to connect to the 5 GHz **ChurchAudio** network. That one is called `Wireless Connection 5`

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to work correctly — for two big reasons:

1. By default, *both* adapters try to connect to **ChurchInternet**. This is obviously not desirable, but I don't know how to make it not do that by default. Here's what it looks like on start up:

   [image]

   And this is what `ipconfig` looks like on initial start up:

   [image]

   I blurred it out here but I can tell you that it gives itself two different sets of IP addresses for the same connection. This is bad and I don't want it to do that! I want it be smart enough to know that `Wireless Connection 5` should connect to **ChurchAudio** instead.
2. Even after I manually disconnect `Wirless Connection 5` from **ChurchInternet** and then manually tell it connect to connect to **ChurchAudio** instead, I become unable to actually use the Internet, and I have no idea why. Everything at that point looks like it should be working — this is what I see in Windows Network & Sharing Center:

   [image]

   But that graphic is deceiving. Even though it says it has Internet access, and recognizes that the **ChurchInternet** network has Internet access, I can't actually connect to anything. Ping requests time out. Browser requests just get stuck on a blank screen before eventually dying. By all accounts, it seems like it's trying to reach the Internet through **ChurchAudio** while completely ignoring the fact that it's connected to **ChurchInternet**.

How do I get this working?

Comment: you might want to try manually setting the connection metric of `Wireless Network Connection 13` to a lower value like 1. And set the metric of `Wireless Network Connection 5` to a higher value like 10. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/PBTiUSc.png

Comment: Additionally, refer to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/455965/how-to-give-preference-over-one-network-connection-over-another) and [this HowToGeek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27994/how-to-change-the-priority-of-wiredwireless-network-cards-in-windows/)

Comment: Vinayak, the tip about changing the connection metric did the trick. If you want to type that into an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what has worked for me on several occasions:

Try setting the interface metric of `Wireless Network Connection 13` to a low value like 1.
And set the metric of `Wireless Network Connection 5` to a higher value like 10.

Here's how you do this:

1. In the Run command box (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), enter `shell:ConnectionsFolder`
2. Select **Wireless Network Connection 13** and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. In the Properties window that pops up, scroll down to find:
   **Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)** and double click it.
4. In the window that pops up, click the **Advanced** button and uncheck **Automatic metric** and set the interface metric to a low value like 1 and click OK.

Do the same thing with **Wireless Network Connection 5** but set its interface metric to a higher value (like 10, for instance).

For further reference, take a look at [this HowToGeek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27994/how-to-change-the-priority-of-wiredwireless-network-cards-in-windows/) or this [SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/455965/how-to-give-preference-over-one-network-connection-over-another).

Answer (score 0):

Either it's windows being stuffy (Which you can't do anything about). Or you only have one wireless networking card. IF thats the case and you're on a desktop you can buy another card like these: http://www.amazon.com/b?node=13983711 if you're on a laptop there's nothing you can do short of extreme hardware mods.