# Wired network icon, but wireless network

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I'm connected to a wireless network, yet in the taskbar the icon is showing that I'm connected to a wired network. Why is that? There is no network cable connected to the laptop, and it says "Limited" below the name of my network.

Lenovo IdeaPad U410
Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit
(Recently installed Oracle VM VirtualBox and a couple of VMs)

Comment: Have you tried going into "change network settings", right clicking on the wired network and setting it to disabled?

Comment: That returns the icon to wireless, though the connection is then limited and I can't connect to the internet.

Comment: VPNs can cause this as well as they establish a separate connection to route all traffic.

Comment: This is definitely a problem due to the VMs as they also require network drivers of their own which usually messes up woth windows.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because the Wired Network Interface Card has precedence over the WiFi-adapter.
Try changing the priority-order of your interface cards. See the question [How to give preference over one network connection over another?](https://superuser.com/questions/455965/how-to-give-preference-over-one-network-connection-over-another) how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on network icon
2. Open Network and Sharing Center
3. Change adapter settings (on left side menu)
4. Right click on Wi-Fi
5. Click on Unbridge Connections

Comment: I am not getting the wifi option in "network and internet" - "network connections".